# SQL query - List albums where every song matches criteria

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am analyzing my music database which uses SQLite. I am trying to get a list of all albums where all the songs on that album having a rating of 10 or less.

Some contrived data for the example:

```
ALBUM       SONG            RATING
Coda        Poor Tom        10
Coda        Darlene         5
Coda        Hey Hey         20
Presence    For Your Life   10
Presence    Royal Orleans   5
Presence    Tea for One     10
```

Using this example data, I would want my query to return "Presence" since all the songs on that album have a rating of 10 or less.

I know enough to get the list of all album names, or the list of all songs with a rating of 10 or less, but I don't know enough to combine them - let alone when EVERY song on an album fits my criteria. I'm sure there's just some key word that I don't know about so don't know what to research.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group by `album` and take only those groups having a max `rating` of `10` for every song

```
select album
from your_table
group by album
having max(rating) <= 10
```

Comment: Many thanks! "having" was the key word I didn't know about, and "max" will certainly be useful.

Comment: `having` is the `where` clause for groups. It handles aggregated records and not just a single record as `where`  does.